# How to prove greedy algorithm for number partitioning?

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

> the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (or number partitioning[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)) is the task of
>   deciding whether a given multiset S of positive integers can be
>   partitioned into two subsets S1 and S2 such that the sum of the
>   numbers in S1 equals the sum of the numbers in S2.

There is a greedy algorithm for this problem:

> One approach to the problem, imitating the way children choose teams
>   for a game, is the greedy algorithm, which iterates through the
>   numbers in descending order, assigning each of them to whichever
>   subset has the smaller sum. This approach has a running time of O(n
>   log n). This heuristic works well in practice when the numbers in the
>   set are of about the same size as its cardinality or less, but it is
>   not guaranteed to produce the best possible partition. For example,
>   given the set S = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8} as input, this greedy algorithm
>   would partition S into subsets {4, 5, 8} and {6, 7}; however, S has an
>   exactly balanced partition into subsets {7, 8} and {4, 5, 6}.

But, I don't know how to prove "This heuristic works well in practice when the numbers in the set are of about the same size as its cardinality or less". Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't prove that "This heuristic works well in practice" because that is not a statement of mathematics, so it is not accessible to proof.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39693921/781723, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/63882/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to prove about the statement you highlight. It is an *empirical* statement.

In order to have something to prove, you will need to formulate this claim formally in some way or another. There are many options, including average-case analysis, smoothed analysis, and restricted instances (which is what the statement points at). Until you have done so, it is impossible to prove or refute the statement.

The example given in your source shows that, in fact, the heuristic doesn't always succeed. Perhaps it gives a good approximation in some circumstances. The statement, unfortunately, doesn't hint at a provable claim which has any chance of being true.

Comment: You can, of course, perform experiments to validate the statement empirically. That is the closest you could get to "proof".

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is just an approximate algorithm for the Job Shop problem (which is also NP-complete, reduced from Partition -- split a set of integers in two so that both add to the same value, the problem you describe) that can be shown has an approximation ratio of 2. See for example [this set of slides](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pearson/11ApproximationAlgorithms.pdf) for a proof and hints at refinements that get better approximation ratio.